# PermissionOverwrites.create() not working as intended when parameters seem to be right

Tags: discord.js

My code below simply shoots out the error `Supplied parameter is not a User nor a Role.` I am able to console.log() the permission and role (including role.id) but it still doesn't seem to work. I have double checked that the bot as administrative access too.

```
 if (interaction.commandName == "addchannelperms") {
          const permission = interaction.options.get("permission1").value
          const role = interaction.options.getRole("role").id
          const channel = interaction.options.getChannel("channel")

          console.log(interaction.options.getRole("role").id)

          channel.permissionOverwrites.create({role, allow: [permission]}
    
          ).catch((error => console.log(error)))
        }
```

I'd expect the code to add the permissions the user selected onto the certain channel, w/ the role.

Comment: Does: `channel.permissionOverwrites.create([{ id: role, allow: [permission] }]);` works ?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://old.discordjs.dev/#/docs/discord.js/14.13.0/class/PermissionOverwriteManager) is `channel.permissionOverwrites`. Scroll down to the method you are using (`create()`). As you can see, it accepts three parameters, two of which are required. You have only provided one.

There is an example in the documentation too.